# Spatie-laravel-analytics package ga:users not accurate

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

My query to fetch data from google analytics using `spatie-laravel-analytics`

```
$analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(Period::days(30),
    'ga:',
    [
        'metrics' => 'ga:users,ga:newUsers,ga:sessions,ga:sessionsPerUser,ga:pageviews,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:bounceRate',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pageTitle',
        'start-date' => '2018-08-01',
        'end-date' => '2018-08-31',
    ]);
```

When I tried to see what's the result inside this is what I got.

[image: GA]

And when I compare it to my google analytics 6/8 is working properly[image]

Is there anyone having this kind of issue? My problem is my `ga:users` is not accurate from google analytics that's why my `ga:sessionPerUser` is giving me a incorrect value as well. Do you have any idea how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your laravel code, you are calling a period of days(30), while in your date range, it is actually 31 days, this might be the cause.

Use this for creating the period that you want and pass it in and remove the start-end dates from your query.

```
$startDate = Carbon::now()->subYear();
$endDate = Carbon::now();

Period::create($startDate, $endDate);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Been used that already and nothing change. I put the start-date and end date just to see the same value on my ga and compare. But then again users are broken.

Comment: Another thing to note, you are pulling a dimension with your query, while the Ga dashboard isn’t doing the same. Can you remove that dimension from your query?

Comment: Let me try it!~

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.